# Experimental Design: Split Plot with 2 whole plot factors and 1 subplot factor. Understanding Error Terms

Tags: r, experiment-design, split-plot

I usually have a little bit better experimental design, but this experiment has already been planted and can't be changed.  Instead of being a true split plot design, in which case I would use ssp.plot in the R package agricolae, I have a 3x2 factorial split plot experiment.  Factor A and Factor B are whole plot factors, and Factor C is a subplot factor.

There are 3 Reps (blocks); Factor A has 3 levels (F1,F2,F3); Factor B has 2 levels (V1,V2); and Factor C has 2 levels (PP1,PP2)

[image]

I'm a little bit confused about the Degrees of Freedom in Error B.  When I try to do this in R, I've been using the code

```
AOV<-aov(Yield ~  factor(Rep)+(factor(Fertility)*factor(Variety))*factor(PlantPop) + Error(factor(Rep)/(factor(Fertility)*factor(Variety))/factor(PlantPop)))

summary(AOV)
```

And I get an output that is close, but it isn't quite the degrees of freedom that I expected.

[image]

This is making me unsure about the degrees of freedom I expected for error B (in the Excel image).  Near as I can tell, the DF from the R output must be coming from (r-1)(PP-1)FV and not from (r-1)(PP-1)(FV-1) as I expected.  Is my R code off, or am I expecting the wrong error B.  And If so, why is this error B more correct?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: Hey.  Thanks for the advice on staying on topic.  I will try to amend the post.   my problem is managing the df of the error and using the right divisors so that I can make sure I am getting the correct P-Values.  pretty simple in ssp.plot  — if well-designed experiment.  But in this case, rather than two true splits. I think the experiment is more like a factorial experiment in which each plot was then split into two in order to have another factor added.  The R code, and if — theoretically —I can even parse out individual Factor A and B effects from this design are of interest to me.

Comment: Hey gung,  I think it is more on-topic with statistical theory now.  Let me know if that is more what you were looking for. Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not very good at setting up sums of squares, but I do note that you have 36 observations. The R code shows 35 df total, as I would have expected, while the Excel excerpt only accounts for 33 df.